# in my simulation some of the water is stuck on walls blender 2.82

Tags: fluid-simulation

so i tried water simulation (pouring water in glass) and the water is almost stuck in the wall and wery slowly going down blue particles on the picture blender: 2.82[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to the **Liquid** menu. Check **Fractional Obstacles**, and drag that value all the way up to **1**.

The reason this is happening is that the fluid simulator is actually based upon lots of 3D "cells". The cup, in a fluid simulation point of view, is basically a lot of obstacle cubes stacked together. The size of these cubes is determined by the fluid resolution. This causes a stair-stepping effect like the one you are seeing, where the liquid stands on a seemingly sloped surface.

By using the **Fraction Obstacles** feature, it is telling the fluid simulator to make the cell representation of an obstacle more like the original mesh bysmoothing it out.